# Change UIView backgrundColor reset round corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

I need to change the bg color of my custom class button, made of a `UIView` and an `UIButton`.

```
    - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame color:(UIColor*)color imageName:(NSString*)imageName target:(id)target action:(SEL)action tag:(int)tag{

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        self.frame = frame;

        CircleStatusView * view = [[CircleStatusView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds color:color];
        view.tag = 22;
        [self addSubview:view];

        UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn.frame = self.bounds;
        [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [btn setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btn setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        btn.tag = tag;
        [self addSubview:btn];


    }
    return self;

}
```

I change the backgroundColor of the `UIView` when the `UIButton` is pressed using this method. I change from gray to green:

```
 - (void)changeBackgroundColor:(UIColor*)color{

        [(CircleStatusView*)[self viewWithTag:22] setBackgroundColor:color];

    }
```

The CircleStatusView is made in this way:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame color:(UIColor*)color{

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        self.frame = frame;
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3;
        self.backgroundColor = color;
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width/2;

        self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;

    }
    return self;

}
```

My issue is that the corner radius of the view disappears and the view became a square instead of remain a circle, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling setBackgroundColor: instead of changeBackgroundColor:, Dumb error